# Given an adjacency list for multigraph, compute adjacency list for equivalent (simple) undirected graph in O(|V|+|E|) time

Tags: algorithm, graph, adjacency-list

We are given the adjacency list for a multigraph, G = (V, E) and need to find an O(V + E) algorithm to compute the adjacency list of an equivalent (simple) undirected graph.

I found the following solution in another post (it was part of the question section hence my repost):

"[H]aving an array of size |V| so as to mark the vertices that have been encountered at least once in adj[u], and thus preventing duplicates. The array is reset before traversing each adj[u]."

Forgive my ignorance, but I'm not sure how this is O(|V| + |E|).  What is the cost of resetting a length |V| array |V| times?

Thank you.

Comment: Depends upon what you consider as reseting. Could be anything from allocating a fresh memory and deleting the old one, overwriting every value with 0 to simply ignoring the old values and starting to write at 0. The citation lacks context to judge this. And the major issue with runtime-complexity is that it highly depends upon **what** is measured (usually the most expensive operation, but that is pretty vague here).

Comment: Hi @Paul.  Can you think of any interpretation of 'resetting' that could satisfy the complexity requirement?  I don't think we can just ignore old values...

Comment: If you keep a list of the vertices which have been set then you can just reset only those array locations, so unsets cost no more than sets and you can treat them as just a constant factor on the cost of sets. Another way is to set a location in the array by setting it to an integer value and to increment that integer value with each traverse, treating as unset any locations set to a value less than the current value.

Comment: @tarski there's quite a bit of ambiguity in time-complexity. For example one could consider heap-memory-allocation as `O(1)`. In that case simply reallocating the array would be sufficient to satisfy the runtime-requirement.

Comment: @mcdowella, the first approach makes sense.  Thank you.  The second one won't work, at least not just by incrementing a counter, since, say, on the second time through (when considering adj[v] for second v in list), if the counter for a node u reads 1, we won't know whether that was from the first pass or the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to actually reset the array.

Say the array stores int. A vertex is marked iff `mark[u] == v` where `v` is the index or id of the current vertex.

When you move to the next vertex the value of `v` changes and all the entries in the array will evaluate to false without having to change the values in the array.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense.

Comment: Wording was a little confusing, but the solution works. Thanks for asking the question and for the answer, @tarski